# Ubuntu Studio Keyboard Shortcuts Audio Volume

Tags: shortcut-keys, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control, ubuntu-studio

I'd like to control the master volume with the designated volume buttons. I'm using Ubuntu Studio and it's got both Pulse and Jack.

Now, I think I would be happy if I could control PulseAudio because I normally stop Jack when I don't need it. I've tried the command `amixer set Master 5%+` but it didn't work. I thought it would control ALSA, which is under either Jack or Pulse. Is that correct?

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Is the command `„amixer set Master 5%+”` or `amixer set Master 5%+`? I have suggested an edit for the latter.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the difference is... I only used quotation marks to set the code apart from the text.

Comment: Alright, in that case, I have handled it properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug with xfce4-volumed. Only workaround at this time is to open a terminal and type `killall xfce4-volumed && xfce4-voumed`.

Links to bug reports:

https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15332

https://launchpad.net/bugs/1291855